# Canvas Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, canvas

I want to drag and drop images into a canvas, and make them draggable. so far this is all i can find but once the text has been dropped into the canvas it is no longer draggable.

`enter code here`http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/6WpKf/

Please someone help me :D

Comment: You cannot bind events to things drawn on the canvas (directly). Look at the canvas object and you will see that there are no elements inside to click, even after the drop. I would say the workaround is to bind a click event to the canvas itself, and use mouse position to determine what you clicked, then redraw on mouse move... or use SVG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Zack Argyle says, any drawing on html canvas is just paint on a canvas--it can't be dragged.

**How to drag text on html canvas:**

- Use jquery draggable to drag a listitem onto the canvas (as you've already done)
- Put info about that text into an object (text, x & y position, text width & height)
- Add that text object to an array that holds all text on the canvas
- When the user starts a drag, find which text is under the mouse (the selected text)
- As the user drags, move the selected text by the distance the user has dragged

You must repaint all text on the canvas every time the user drags any text to a new location.

Here's code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hQTLa/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
      body{ background-color: ivory; }
      canvas{border:1px solid red;}
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {

        // get reference to the canvas and its context
        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = "16px helvetica";

        // variables

        // some text objects defining text on the canvas
        var texts=[];

        // variables used to get mouse position on the canvas
        var $canvas=$("#canvas");
        var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
        var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
        var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
        var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
        var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

        // variables to save last mouse position
        // used to see how far the user dragged the mouse
        // and then move the text by that distance
        var startX;
        var startY;

        // this var will hold the index of the selected text
        var selectedText=-1;


        // make the <li> draggable 
        $("li").draggable({
            helper: 'clone'
        });

        // drop on canvas
        $("#canvas").droppable({
            accept: "li",
            drop: function(event,ui){
                ctx.fillText($(ui.draggable).clone().text(),ui.position.left - event.target.offsetLeft,ui.position.top - event.target.offsetTop);

                var text=$(ui.draggable).clone().text();
                var x=ui.position.left - event.target.offsetLeft;
                var y=ui.position.top - event.target.offsetTop;
                var width=ctx.measureText(text).width;
                var height=16;

                // save this text info in an object in texts[]
                texts.push({text:text,x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height});

                // draw all texts to the canvas
                draw();

            }
        });

        // clear the canvas draw all texts
        function draw(){
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
                var text=texts[i];
                ctx.fillText(text.text,text.x,text.y);
            }
        }

        // test if x,y is inside the bounding box of texts[textIndex]
        function textHittest(x,y,textIndex){
            var text=texts[textIndex];
            return(x>=text.x && 
                x<=text.x+text.width &&
                y>=text.y-text.height && 
                y<=text.y);
        }

        // handle mousedown events
        // iterate through texts[] and see if the user
        // mousedown'ed on one of them
        // If yes, set the selectedText to the index of that text
        function handleMouseDown(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
          // Put your mousedown stuff here
          for(var i=0;i<texts.length;i++){
              if(textHittest(startX,startY,i)){
                  selectedText=i;
              }
          }
        }

        // done dragging
        function handleMouseUp(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          selectedText=-1;
        }

        // also done dragging
        function handleMouseOut(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          selectedText=-1;
        }

        // handle mousemove events
        // calc how far the mouse has been dragged since
        // the last mousemove event and move the selected text
        // by that distance
        function handleMouseMove(e){
          if(selectedText<0){return;}
          e.preventDefault();
          mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
          mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

          // Put your mousemove stuff here
          var dx=mouseX-startX;
          var dy=mouseY-startY;
          startX=mouseX;
          startY=mouseY;

          var text=texts[selectedText];
          text.x+=dx;
          text.y+=dy;
          draw();
        }

        // listen for mouse events
        $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
        $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
        $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});


  });   // end $(function(){});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="drag">
        <li class="new-item">Drag me down1</li>
        <li class="new-item">Drag me down2</li>
        <li class="new-item">Drag me down3</li>
    </ul>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well done. I feel like at this point I would probably give up on canvas and just use absolutely positioned elements. Impressive tho.

Comment: @ZackArgyle, before you give up on canvas, maybe you would want to do something interesting with that text after it's dragged to the canvas  ;)  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2JjYY/

Comment: The text becomes blurry on the canvas. Is there a way to prevent that?